# JS. Регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Делаю задания на регулярные выражения, но не получается корректно вывести то, что нужно.

1. Постройте регулярное выражение, которое соответствует любому числу обратных косых, за которым следует любое количество звездочек (любое число может быть и нулем).
   Делаю так:

   ```
   let myRe = /(\\*\**)/g;
   let str = "djfhhj\\\****jjd";
   let ma = str.match(myRe);
   alert(ma);
   ```

   Должен вывести `"\\\****"`, а выводит `",,,,,,\****,,,,"`.

2. Постройте регулярное выражение, которое соответствует любым пяти символам, включая символ новой строки.
   Делаю так:

   ```
   let myRe = /(.|\n){5}/;
   let str = "hello world";
   alert( str.search(myRe));
   ```

   Должен вывести "hello", а выводит "hello,о"
3. Постройте регулярное выражение, которое соответствует одному слову, написанному два или более раз подряд (с возможно изменяющимся пробельным символом), где слово определяется как непустая последовательность непробельных символов. При решении задачи использовать механизм группировок.
   Тут я точно не знаю, что надо вывести. Я думаю, что повторяющее слово столько раз, сколько оно повторяется.

   ```
   let myRe = /\b(\w+)\s+\1\b/g;
   let str = "hello my my my friend";
   alert( str.match(myRe));
   ```

   Но так выводится повторяющееся слово только два раза, даже если оно повторяется 3 раза, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас небольшая путаница: вы используете то `match()`, to `search()`, то с флагом `g`, то без, поэтому в alert, превращающий массивы в строку, попадает разный тип результатов. Попробуйте соблюдать однообразие. И, если это разрешено, используйте `console.log()`, так будут яснее видны результаты.

Также не забывайте экранировать специальные символы в строках и регулярных выражениях.

Странность результата в первом задании от того, что регулярка будет то и дело совпадать с нулём символов, от этого большое количество пустых строк в результатах.

```js
let myRe = /\\*\**/g;
let str = "djfhhj\\****jjd";
console.log(str.match(myRe));

myRe = /(.|\n){5}/g; // варианты: /[^]{5}/g или /[\s\S]{5}/g или /.{5}/gs
str = "hello world";
console.log(str.match(myRe));

myRe = /(?<=^|\s)(\S+)(?:\s+\1(?=\s|$))+/g;
str = "hello my my my friend";
console.log(str.match(myRe));
```

Answer (score 0):

Отформатируйте свой текст, его практически невозможно читать.

1. `\\*\**` - экранируем скобку, поэтому их две: `\\`, указываем, что их может быть любое количество: `*`. Потом экранируем звёздочку и указываем, что их может быть любое количество: `\**`
2. `.{5}` - если там действительно могут быть любые пять символов, то вот оно.